# Prove that the set $A(d)=\{m\in\mathbb{Z}|1\leq m\leq n\quad\&\quad gcd(m,n)=d\}$ are pairwise disjoint

Tags: number-theory, elementary-set-theory, totient-function, coprime

Let $n\in\mathbb{Z}_+$ then $n=\sum_{d|n} \phi(d)$, where $\sum_{d|n} $ denotes the sum over all of the divisors of $n$ and $\phi(d)$ is the Euler phi function which gives the number of integers less than $d$ which are coprime to $d$.

In order to prove this, define set
$$
A(d)=\{m\in\mathbb{Z}|1\leq m\leq n\quad\&\quad gcd(m,n)=d\}\\
gcd(m,n)=d: d|m \Leftrightarrow m=ds\quad\&\quad d|n \Leftrightarrow n=dt\text{ for some }s,t\in\mathbb{Z}\\
\text{Bezout's identity : } d=mx+ny \text{ for some }x,y\in\mathbb{Z}\\
\implies d=dsx+dty\implies 1=sx+ty\\
\implies gcd(s,t)=gcd(m/d,n/d)=1
$$
Since $A(d)$ is all the numbers less than or equal to $n$ whose gcd with $n$ is $d$, implies the number of integers in $A(d)$, i.e., $|A(d)|$ equals the number of positive inegers less than or equal to $n/d$ that are coprime to $n/d$. Therefore,
$$
|A(d)|=\phi(n/d)
$$

This much is clear. But, in order to finish the proof we need to prove that $A(d)$ are pairwise disjoint, how does one show this ?

**My Attempt**

Each such sets can be restated as, $A(n/d)=\{m/d\in\mathbb{Z}|1\leq m/d\leq n/d\quad\&\quad gcd(m/d,n/d)=1\}$

$d_1,\cdots,d_r$ are divisors of $n$, therefore $n/d_1,\cdots,n/d_r$ are divisors of $n$ in a different same order.

So we can restate the sets as $A(d)=\{m\in\mathbb{Z}|1\leq m\leq n\quad\&\quad gcd(m,n)=1\}$ and we have show them as pairwise disjoint.

Comment: I'm not sure if I've understand correctly but, aren't the $A(d)$ disjoint because of the unicity of the gcd?

Comment: @Eparoh Thanks for responding. I only have basic understanding of Number theory. Could ypu please elaborate on that ?

Comment: I mean, suppose that $m \in A(d) \cap A(d')$ with $d \not = d'$. Then, we have that $gcd(m,n)= d$ and $gcd(m,n)=d'$, but $gcd(m,n)$ is the greatest common divisor of both $m$ and $n$, so it is unique, and we get that $d=d'$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Compare with some other posts doing this proof, e.g., [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2585843/alternative-proof-of-n-sum-dn-phid-which-is-the-sum-of-euler-phi-fu?rq=1).

Comment: @Eparoh Thanks in think that's what I was looking for.